# What is the decent approach to resizing images in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, image-resizing

It's my first time resizing images in ASP.NET Core, so after a bit of research I found this approach to be the easiest and most efficient and I implemented it as shown below.

However, I am not sure if that approach is the most efficient one since there are two issues with it that go as follows

1. Images lose a lot of their quality
2. I get this 'warning' in Visual Studio that is fine as long as I am the only one who develops it, however that will not always be the case if someone else does -

> This call site is reachable on all platforms. 'Bitmap' is only supported on windows.

Therefore I wonder what are other approaches more decent that exist and I can implement to at least fix the first of both issues.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Add(AddCardFormModel card, List<IFormFile> ImageFile)
{
    // ...

    foreach (var image in ImageFile)
    {
        if (image.Length > 0 || image.Length <= (2 * 1024 * 1024))
        {
            var imagesToBeResized = Image.FromStream(image.OpenReadStream());
            var resized = new Bitmap(imagesToBeResized, new Size(250, 350));

            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                resized.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                var cardData = new Card
                        {
                            Title = card.Title,
                            Description = card.Description,
                            ImageUrl = card.ImageUrl,
                            CategoryId = card.CategoryId,
                            ConditionId = card.ConditionId,
                            Price = card.Price,
                            DealerId = dealerId,
                            Image = stream.ToArray()
                        };

                this.data.Cards.Add(cardData);
                this.data.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `System.Drawing.Common` package is only supported on Windows.

If you want your application to work cross-platform then Microsoft suggests to migrate to one of the following libraries:

- [ImageSharp](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp)
- [SkiaSharp](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp)
- [Microsoft.Maui.Graphics](https://github.com/dotnet/Microsoft.Maui.Graphics)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/system-drawing-common-windows-only#recommended-action

You should first decide which image processing library you will use in your project and after that look for the best algorithm for resizing images using that specific library.

**SkiaSharp example:**

```
using SkiaSharp;

public static byte[] ScaleImage(byte[] imageBytes, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
{
    SKBitmap image = SKBitmap.Decode(imageBytes);

    var ratioX = (double)maxWidth / image.Width;
    var ratioY = (double)maxHeight / image.Height;
    var ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);

    var newWidth = (int)(image.Width * ratio);
    var newHeight = (int)(image.Height * ratio);

    var info = new SKImageInfo(newWidth, newHeight);
    image = image.Resize(info, SKFilterQuality.High);

    using var ms = new MemoryStream();
    image.Encode(ms, SKEncodedImageFormat.Png, 100);
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

**ImageSharp example:**

```
using SixLabors.ImageSharp;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.Formats.Png;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.Processing;

public static byte[] ScaleImage(byte[] imageBytes, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
{
    Image image = Image.Load(imageBytes);   

    var ratioX = (double)maxWidth / image.Width;
    var ratioY = (double)maxHeight / image.Height;
    var ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);

    var newWidth = (int)(image.Width * ratio);
    var newHeight = (int)(image.Height * ratio);

    image.Mutate(x => x.Resize(newWidth, newHeight));

    using var ms = new MemoryStream();
    image.Save(ms, new PngEncoder());
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Note that ImageSharp library has changed a license to Six Labors Split License. If you are consuming the package as a direct dependency of a for-profit, you might need a commercial license.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [library](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) for image resizing.

but I suggest don't store images on the database, because the database size and log size will be increased.

you have 2 options:

Option 1: store resized images on directories and save names in the database.

Option 2: store the original size on directories and resize it in real-time.